# Python Dataframe iterate over rows ( compare a values between them) and prepare a groups as output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this
I want to group them by url and status and split  a records by date, is it a more efficient way to do that?

```
def transform_to_unique(df):
    test = []
    counter = 0

    #first_row
    if df.loc[0, 'status']!= df.loc[1, 'status']:
        counter = counter +1
    test.append(counter)

    for i in range(1, len(df)):

        if df.loc[i-1, 'url']!= df.loc[i, 'url']:
            counter=0

        if df.loc[i-1, 'status']!= df.loc[i, 'status'] :
            counter = counter +1
        test.append(counter)

    df['test'] = pd.Series(test)

    return df

df = transform_to_unique(frame)

df_g = df.groupby(['url', 'status', 'test'])['date_scraped'].agg({min, max})
```

[image: ouptut from script]

Here is a dataframe:

```
1000,20191109,active
1000,20191108,inactive
2000,20191109,active
2000,20191101,inactive
351,20191109,active
351,20191102,active
351,20191026,active
351,20191019,active
351,20191012,active
351,20191005,active
351,20190928,inactive
351,20190921,inactive
351,20190914,inactive
351,20190907,active
351,20190831,active
351,20190615,inactive
3000,20200101,active
```

```
import pandas as pd
frame =pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", header=None)
frame.columns = ['url', 'date_scraped', 'status']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, whether I'm getting correctly where are you heading with the `test` column, but is this what you want to achieve (based on the sample data, you posted):

```py
import numpy as np

df.sort_values(["url", "date_scraped"], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)

df["date_scraped_till"]=np.where(df["url"]==df["url"].shift(-1), 

df["date_scraped"].shift(-1), np.nan).astype(np.int32)
```

Output:

```py
     url  date_scraped    status  date_scraped_till
15   351      20190615  inactive           20190831
14   351      20190831    active           20190907
13   351      20190907    active           20190914
12   351      20190914  inactive           20190921
11   351      20190921  inactive           20190928
10   351      20190928  inactive           20191005
9    351      20191005    active           20191012
8    351      20191012    active           20191019
7    351      20191019    active           20191026
6    351      20191026    active           20191102
5    351      20191102    active           20191109
4    351      20191109    active                  0
1   1000      20191108  inactive           20191109
0   1000      20191109    active                  0
3   2000      20191101  inactive           20191109
2   2000      20191109    active                  0
16  3000      20200101    active                  0
```

**Edit**

If instead of "splitted" you meant "collapsed", this should do the trick (it's basically more efficient way of doing your `test` column):

```py
import numpy as np

df.sort_values(["url", "date_scraped"], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)

df["test"]=np.where((df["url"]==df["url"].shift(1)) & (df["status"]==df["status"].shift(1)), 0,1)

df["test"]=df.groupby(["url", "status", "test"])["test"].cumsum().replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')

df_g = df.groupby(['url', 'status', 'test'])['date_scraped'].agg({min, max})
```

Output:

```py
                    max       min
url  status   test
351  active   1     20190907  20190831
              2     20191109  20191005
     inactive 1     20190615  20190615
              2     20190928  20190914
1000 active   1     20191109  20191109
     inactive 1     20191108  20191108
2000 active   1     20191109  20191109
     inactive 1     20191101  20191101
3000 active   1     20200101  20200101
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, this is good :-) I have to learn more about groupbing, i did not know that i can group by some field and use them in [] bracket after that  df.groupby(["url", "status", "test"])["test"].cumsum()